# Flat collision mesh in bullet causes balls to roll around

Tags: physics, bulletphysics

I've got a simple collision mesh which I am using in bullet to model the surface of a pool table. All of the vertices are level with each other (y = 0), but when I put pool balls on the surface (using btSphereShape), gravity causes them to roll around. I know it's gravity because turning off gravity prevents the issue, while turning up gravity exacerbates it.

This is my mesh in blender:

[image: Collision mesh]

What is probably my issue, and what is the best way to fix it?

Comment: Totally unfamiliar with bullet, but perhaps this is caused by rounding errors. Maybe there is some threshold value to set, which makes calculation results zero if too small. Or something. Also perhaps your balls aren't round enough?

Comment: Normally that idea might be helpful - but bullet is entirely undocumented. There's a list of functions and parameters, but no description of what each does. So you're probably right - but I have no idea what to search for. Also, I'm using btSphereShape - which is a perfectly round sphere, no collision mesh.

Comment: Narrow triangles introduce a certain amount of numerical error in the vector cross-products required in collision algorithms; have you tried covering the table geometry with as large quads as possible?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog That's worked perfectly! Thanks for explaining why it happens, as well.